# function definite integral with c language

Tags: c, math, integral

I want to make definite integral, but it seems error, can anyone help me? I'm sorry I make variable with Indonesian language. I want to appearing f(bawah) and f(atas) but Idk how to insert that input to the void function (input is "bawah" and "atas")

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void f(float a, float b, float c, float x) {
    return(a*(pow(x, 2) + (b*x) + c); }

void integral(float atas, float bawah, int suku, float a, float b, float c, float h, float result, int i) {
    h = ((atas-bawah)/suku);
    result = 0.5 * f(bawah) + 0.5 * f(atas);
    for(i=0;i<suku;i++) result += f(bawah+(i*h));
    result *= h;
    return result; }

int main() {
    int atas,bawah,suku;
    float a,b,c;

    printf("Integral Tentu\n");
    printf("Bentuk umum (ax^2) + (bx) + (c) \n");
    printf("Masukkan nilai a : ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Masukkan nilai b : ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("Masukkan nilai c : ");
    scanf("%f", &c);
    printf("Fungsinya adalah :"); printf("%f", a); printf("x^2 + "); printf("%f", b); printf("x + "); printf("%f \n", c);
    printf("Masukkan batas bawah: ");
    scanf("%f", &atas);
    printf("Masukkan batas atas: ");
    scanf("%f", &bawah);
    printf("Masukkan jumlah suku: ");
    scanf("%d", &suku);
    printf("The Answer = "); 
    printf("%d", integral())
     }
```

Comment: The function `integral()` requires 9 arguments (if I count correctly).  You attempt to call it with 0 arguments.  Your compiler won't like that.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
void f(float a, float b, float c, float x) {
    return(a*(pow(x, 2) + (b*x) + c); }
```

the first `void` says that `f` does not return anything. Then the `return` statement says to return a value. These conflict. For your function to return a value, change `void` to the type you want to return, such as `float f(float a, float b, float c, float x)`.

The `(float a, float b, float c, float x)` says that `f` takes four values when it is called, for the parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `x`. So, when you call `f`, pass it four values. Instead of calling it with `f(bawah)`, use `f(a, b, c, bawah)`.